# Oracle Join on Delimited String

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables: PROFESSOR and STUDENT. Both have a LEVEL columns, which contains "," delimited value. If I have a STUDENT, how can I write a query to return all the PROFESSORs matches at least 1 STUDENT.LEVEL?

For example:

```
STUDENT[1].LEVEL = '1,2' 
PROFESSOR[1].LEVEL = '2, 3' 
PROFESSOR[2].LEVEL = '2, 4'
```

I want to return both PROFESSOR 1 and 2.

Comment: So for student 1, you want to return 2, 3 and 4...? Or you 1 and 2? Seem like you already have 1 and 2

Comment: I want to return PROFESSOR[1] and PROFESSOR[2].

Comment: But you already have that in student.level..? Right? So what would the query do?

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend normalizing your data.  You're basically asking to join by looking for EACH VALUE in one comma-delimited string within another comma-delimited string.  SQL isn't designed for parsing delimited data in general, let alone doing it TWICE.

Comment: @kbball I think the join criteria is "any value in the student's comma-delimited string is contained in the professor's comma-delimited string"

Comment: Are the strings really comma-delimited or can they (as in the example you gave) include spaces as well?

Comment: Whatever solution you might come up with: expect horrible performance for any reasonably large database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As D Stanley said you need normalize your data.
But anyway, your problem has a solution. Use `REPLACE` for data clearing and `REGEXP` for join.

```
-- data for example
WITH
student AS (
SELECT 'Jon' AS "name", '1,2' AS "level" FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bob' AS "name", '1,5' AS "level" FROM dual
),
professor AS (
SELECT 'M.Fowler' AS "name", '2, 3' AS "level" FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'E.Gamma' AS "name", '2, 4' AS "level" FROM dual
)
-- query
SELECT s.*, p.* 
  FROM student s,
       professor p
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(p."level", REPLACE(REPLACE(s."level",' ', ''), ',', '|'))
```